# Vue js and Firebase

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue Js and Firebase. I want to learn firebase /firestore db connection ,data in/out but i am not getting any proper documentation or tutorial for the same.Please suggest.

I am using VUE CLI 2.

Comment: This question is probably going to get closed. Can you limit the scope of the question to a narrower scope of what you're having issues with?

Comment: I've got an example on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-fast-jy4lm94nv a version of which I've used during technical interviews. The firebase connection is working (the test is to add features like updating test). It is setup so that the `firebase.js` is portable and framework agnostic. I'm sure there are some vue plugins that make it easier, have you looked into any? They often have good docs.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-firestore

Answer (score 0):

Create a src/firebaseDb.js file then add the following code to establish the real-time database connection in vue with your Firebase configurations details.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "api-key",
    authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-id",
    storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
    appId: "app-id",
    measurementId: "G-measurement-id"
}

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
```

You can check this link its quite easy
https://www.positronx.io/vue-js-firebase-build-vue-crud-app-with-cloud-firestore/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

i have created firebaseConfig.js file  and connect to fire store.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
require('firebase/firestore');

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC944Kh9T_Pcdn-kTZ6LywsIUATJBmQNTI",
    authDomain: "halo-care-38f05.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://halo-care-38f05.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "halo-care-38f05",
    storageBucket: "halo-care-38f05.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "682838402004"
};

const firestore =firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
export default db;
```